# How to extract start and end date of quarter?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle, I would like to extract the start and end date of a quarter by passing the quarter value.

For e.g.
v_quarter = 'Q2';

I would like to get the start and end date by passing v_quarter value. Also my fiscal year starts from April. So Q1 would be Apr-Jun, Q2 would be Jul-Sept and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: And how do you determine what a **fiscal month** is? 4-4-5, 52-53 week, Saturday nearest the end of the calendar month, something else? There is so much variation in how fiscal calendars are determined and used that this question is not answerable outside the context of a particular business.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Lines 2 - 4 represent one of *row generator techniques* and create the whole year ("yr"), having 12 months (line 4).

Line 2: `TRUNC` of a `SYSDATE` to `'yyyy'` returns 01.01.2018. By adding months (`level - 1`) twelve times creates months from January to December.

Lines 6 - 9 are "quarters", as the `'q'` format mask applied to a date value returns the quarter. CASE switches the quarter, as your fiscal year begins in April.

Finally, lines 11 - 14 return starting and ending month for quarter you pass as a parameter (line 14; I used `q = 1`, the firstquarter).

```
SQL> with yr as
  2    (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1) mon
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 12
  5    ),
  6  qr as
  7    (select mon,
  8     case to_number(to_char(mon, 'q')) when 1 then 4 when 2 then 1 when 3 then 2 when 4 then 3 end q
  9     from yr
 10    )
 11  select to_char(min(mon), 'mon') min_month,
 12         to_char(max(mon), 'mon') max_month
 13  from qr
 14  where q = 1;

MIN MAX
--- ---
apr jun

SQL>
```